# My android phone charge only when connected to PC

Tags: android, usb, driver, smartphone

When  i connect my Alcatel One-touch 4015D to My PC to access my phone files the phone recognize the PC as a Charger Not as Computer  i had installed Drivers and retested the mobile and the problem still ,
and tried another Samsung phone with the same USB cable and everything working will with Samsung Phone ??
So the Problem is from my phone not from PC or the USB Cable !
anyone can help me ?

Comment: I think this question is off-topic to stack-overflow, as it has nothing to with programming. I think op should migrate this question to http://android.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Your Android Phone should show a push notification saying "USB for charging" or something. It also says "Click for more options" If you do that, you should be able to switch the USB mode to MTP or PTP.

Comment: this is the problem that when i plug in the USB there is no push notification appears Just charging

Comment: I think you should read the Alcatel documentation or write in their forum then. As you said it runs on Samsung. This is a phone specific problem and has nothing to do with your PC drivers or cable or basic Android.